# How to calculate duration between a list of timestamps

Tags: sql, time, timestamp, duration

I have a table with a list of timestamps and I want to calculate the duration between the timestamps
The Table list looks like this

```
MYTIME
2015-01-30-08.12.51.141000
2015-01-30-08.12.51.142000
2015-01-30-08.12.51.142000
2015-01-30-08.12.51.162000
2015-01-30-08.12.51.170000
2015-01-30-08.12.51.290000
```

what I want as a result set is

```
first timestamp next timestamp duration in microseconds
2015-01-30-08.12.51.141000 2015-01-30-08.12.51.142000 1000
2015-01-30-08.12.51.142000 2015-01-30-08.12.51.142000 0000
2015-01-30-08.12.51.142000 2015-01-30-08.12.51.162000 20000
```

I am using DB2 for i SQL but not sure how to do it with pivot table or CTE?

Comment: include something, code, query, tables schema, sample input, expected output

Comment: I know how to calculate duration between 2 timestamps I dont know how to roll through a list and calculate duration

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER(), you should create from this list two enumerated tables and make join.

Comment: How do I split and join this table? I need row 1 duration from row 2 then I need row 2 duration from row 3 etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my DB2 solution:
I have a table with a single column filled with Tags and timestamps;
First I created a CTE to filter to records I wanted then I pulled out tags and timestamps and a newly created rank column.
Then with this CTE table I used the rank to join 1 to 2 then 2 to 3 etc. to get my duration.
*Thanks to Milan for heading me in the right direction.

With TagTimeTable (myTag, myTime, myRank) as
(Select substring(SPOOLRCD FROM 34 FOR 6) AS mytag, CAST(substring(SPOOLRCD FROM 60 FOR 26) AS TIMESTAMP) AS mytime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY substring(SPOOLRCD FROM 60 FOR 26)) as myrank
FROM MYLIB.SPOOLTBL 
WHERE SPOOLRCD LIKE '%DSPLY%' 
order by mytime
)

SELECT cast('0001-01-01 00:00:00.000' as timestamp) + TIMESTAMPDIFF(1, CHAR(time2.myTime - time1.myTime)) MICROSECOND as
TIME_IN_MICROSECONDS,
TIME1.MYTIME,
TIME2.MYTIME
FROM
    TagTimeTable TIME1
    INNER JOIN
    TagTimeTable TIME2
ON (TIME1.myRank=TIME2.myRank-1);

Answer (score 1):

It's depend what SQL server are you using. Does it implemented Window Functions or not?

It would be operation between lines. Previous and Next time stamp difference.

In MS SQL 2008:

```
WITH AUXILIERY_TBL AS (
    SELECT 
      A.[Time_Stamp]
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.[Time_Stamp]) AS Ordr
      FROM [Time_Stamps_TBL] AS A
)

SELECT 
 A.[Time_Stamp] 
,DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,B.[Time_Stamp] ,A.[Time_Stamp] ) AS Duration_Minutes
FROM AUXILIERY_TBL AS A
LEFT JOIN AUXILIERY_TBL AS B
       ON (A.Ordr=(B.Ordr+1))
```

In MS SQL 2012/14 it would be much easier without need of temporary table:

```
SELECT
 A.[Time_Stamp]
,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (LAG(A.[Time_Stamp]) OVER (ORDER BY A.[Time_Stamp])), A.[Time_Stamp]) AS Duration_Minutes
FROM [Time_Stamps_TBL] AS A
```

You can change DATEDIFF function from minutes to hours or seconds, what suit you better.

Comment: DB2 for i server not MS SQL ...but you also might be on track with CTE

Comment: Yes, it is not :) I have start answering you before you have edit your post.

DB2 should have implemented  ROW_NUMBER() function. I assume solution will be similar to 2008 solution above. First temp table to Order time stamps with row number, then join temp to it self with with A.Ordr=(B.Ordr+1)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a DB2 database, but know that DB2 has a ROW_NUMBER() function too. So you can try to apply following approach... (it works on MS SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (dt datetime);

INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT getutcdate() 
UNION ALL 
SELECT dateadd(ms, 7, getutcdate())
UNION ALL 
SELECT dateadd(s, 1, getutcdate())
UNION ALL 
SELECT dateadd(s, 3, getutcdate());

SELECT t1.dt as datetime1, t2.dt as datetime2, DATEDIFF(ms, t1.dt, t2.dt) as diff
FROM (SELECT dt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt)+1 as rn FROM #temp) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT dt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dt) as rn FROM #temp) t2
ON t1.rn = t2.rn

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Result:

```
datetime1   datetime2   diff
2015-01-30 20:57:59.053 2015-01-30 20:57:59.060 6
2015-01-30 20:57:59.060 2015-01-30 20:58:00.053 993
2015-01-30 20:58:00.053 2015-01-30 20:58:02.053 2000
```

Comment: Ok this looks more like it I will just create a CTE instead of the temp table, let me code it and see if this is the solution.